# Seaborn tsplot shows nothing

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame called `amounts_month` of such a type:

```
    product accounting_month    amount
0   A       201404              204748.0
1   A       201405              445064.0
2   B       201404              649326.0
3   B       201405              876738.0
4   C       201404              1046336.0
```

But when I evaluate

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.tsplot(data=amounts_month,
          time='accounting_month',
          value='amount',
           condition='product'
          )
```

I get an empty plot. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try add one more data for product `C`

```
product accounting_month    amount
A       201404          204748.0
A       201405          445064.0
B       201404          649326.0
B       201405          876738.0
C       201404          1046336.0
C       201405          1046336.0
```

then try the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
#change the `accounting_month` to datatime
amounts_month['accounting_month']= pd.to_datetime(amounts_month['accounting_month'], format="%Y%m")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.tsplot(data=amounts_month,
          time='accounting_month',
          value='amount',
           unit='product', # add a unit
           condition='product',
          ax=ax)
def myFormatter(x, pos):
    return pd.to_datetime(x)

# assign locator and formatter for the xaxis ticks.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(myFormatter))

# put the labels at 45deg since they tend to be too long
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So what was the problem here? That one of the time series had only one measurement? I'm facing a similar problem and I'm sure that all of my series have more than one measurement.